# Why += works when inserting string in vector<string> and then pushing in 2d string vector, but doesn't work when inserting char by char?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I was creating a vector of strings of size 4x4 with all characters as dots i.e. I was creating:

```
....
....
....
....
```

And then I had to push this vector of strings in a vector of vector of strings like in the code below:

```
int main()
{
    vector<vector<string>> ans;
    int n=4;
    vector<string> matrix(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j]='.';    //inserting '.' as characters
        }
    }
    
    ans.push_back(matrix);
    
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)   //printing the just inserted matrix
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
           cout<<ans[0][i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    
}
```

This was when I am printing it back, it gives garbage/nothing. But, I change the insertion  `matrix[i][j]='.';` to  `matrix[i]+='.';`, it is working fine.

```
int main()
{
    vector<vector<string>> ans;
    int n=4;
    vector<string> matrix(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            matrix[i]+='.';    //inserting '.' by +=
        }
    }
    
    ans.push_back(matrix);
    
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)   //printing the just inserted matrix
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
           cout<<ans[0][i][j]<<" ";   //works fine
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    
}
```

What is the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: What's the size of the strings in `matrix` when you enter the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
int n=4;
vector<string> matrix(n);
```

Will create a vector filled with `n` default-constructed strings; i.e. a vector with 4 empty strings. So, in the following loop, you're accessing each string with an out-of-bound index (which is *undefined behavior*):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = '.';
               // ^ Out of bounds: matrix[i].size() == 0
    }
}
```

In your second case:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        matrix[i] += '.';
               // ^ You're appending '.' to the string.
               //   That's fine
    }
}
```

you're appending to the strings, which is fine.

If you want to have a vector of `n` strings, each containing `n` times character `'.'`, you may just skip the loop and do:

```
int n = 4;
std::vector<std::string> matrix(n, std::string(n, '.'));
```

---

As a side note, you're not showing it but most probably you are:

```
using namespace std;
```

You [shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) do it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Understood. Also, yes, was using 'using namespace std;' Could you please tell why I shouldn't use it?

Comment: @SnehaSharma You're welcome. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) is a thorough explanation to why you shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see how this doesn't crash outright:

```
vector<string> matrix(n);  // THIS IS A VECTOR OF EMPTY STRINGS

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j]='.';    //inserting '.' as characters
    }
}
```

When you reference `matrix[i]`, you get back an empty string because you haven't assigned anything to that string.  Attempting to access any element in that string and assigning a char to it is going to <s>throw an exception</s> be undefined behavior.

There's an easy fix:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    matrix[i] = string(n ,' ');
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j]='.';    //inserting '.' as characters
    }
}
```

Or simply:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    matrix[i] = string(n ,'.');
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined, it does not have to crash outright. :)

Comment: _"Attempting to access any element in that string and assigning a char to it is going to throw an exception."_ It's not: it's undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm actually surprised it's not guaranteed to throw an exception.  But you are correct, it is UB.

Comment: @selbie You might be thinking about MSVC Debug builds.  They range-check, I believe.

Comment: @PaulSanders - I'm booted into my Linux partition at the moment to validate what msvc does, but you are probably correct.